# uiwebview to uiview

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, uiwebview

When i click a link in the uiwebview is that possible to load a uiview ? Is there a way to transfer control from uiwebview to uiview.

Comment: did you had luck getting it working? or know any tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: if you have a link on the page say link1 then the html will look like <a href = "link1.html>link</a> .. when user clicks the link you just need to find whether the user clicked that url using the delegate methods specified in the answer and then load the view from there . .please dont forget to place a return false statement after opening the new view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method of the [UIWebViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I dont get it completely. How will i control on click of a link on the webview to show another uiview ?

Comment: this method will be called on the UIWebView's delegate when the user "clicks" a link.

Comment: @CanBerkGüder Is this the standard way to change to a different UI view instead of the rendering the link response in the view that was clicked?